# Error when trying to run a stored procedure from my C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ListQuestionIds
    @ExamId int
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT Question.QuestionUId
    FROM Objective
    INNER JOIN ObjectiveDetail
        ON ( Objective.objectiveId = ObjectiveDetail.objectiveId )
    INNER JOIN ObjectiveTopic
        ON ( ObjectiveDetail.ObjectiveDetailId = ObjectiveTopic.ObjectiveDetailId )
    INNER JOIN Problem
        ON ( ObjectiveTopic.SubTopicId = Problem.SubTopicId )
    INNER JOIN Question
        ON ( Problem.ProblemId = Question.ProblemId )
    WHERE Objective.examId = @ExamId;

END;
```

I am using EF6.1 and I have a db context. Here is how I am trying to call the stored procedure:

```
var b = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("dbo.ListQuestionIds", 1);
```

It's giving me an error saying it expects the parameter @ExamId but none is supplied.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve you problem

```
 db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("dbo.ListQuestionIds @ExamId", 
new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "ExamId", Value = 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ExamId", 1);
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.ListQuestionIds",param);
```

or you can also use

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("exec dbo.ListQuestionIds @ExamId",1);
```